# Codeigniter displays a blank page in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7

I have cloned an application from Bitbucket and when run the application through localhost, it displays a complete blank page.
When i downloaded a new codeigniter project from their website and run, it works fine and no issue.
But when i run this pulled project, it displays only blank page and no errors, everything was blank.

I am working in **Ubuntu 16.04** with php version **7.0**

The same project works fine in another system with same configuration as above said but when pulled in new in another system it doesn't work and displays a blank page.

The base url was, `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/school-erp/';`

Index.php file looks like,

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

The setting model is as follows,

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Setting_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * This funtion takes id as a parameter and will fetch the record.
     * If id is not provided, then it will fetch all the records form the table.
     * @param int $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($id = null) {

        $this->db->select('sch_settings.id,sch_settings.lang_id,sch_settings.is_rtl,sch_settings.timezone,
          sch_settings.name,sch_settings.email,sch_settings.phone,languages.language,
          sch_settings.address,sch_settings.dise_code,sch_settings.date_format,sch_settings.currency,sch_settings.currency_symbol,sch_settings.start_month,sch_settings.session_id,sch_settings.image,sessions.session'
        );
        $this->db->from('sch_settings');
        $this->db->join('sessions', 'sessions.id = sch_settings.session_id');
        $this->db->join('languages', 'languages.id = sch_settings.lang_id');
        if ($id != null) {
            $this->db->where('sch_settings.id', $id);
        } else {
            $this->db->order_by('sch_settings.id');
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($id != null) {
            return $query->row_array();
        } else {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will delete the record based on the id
     * @param $id
     */
    public function remove($id) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('sch_settings');
    }

    /**
     * This function will take the post data passed from the controller
     * If id is present, then it will do an update
     * else an insert. One function doing both add and edit.
     * @param $data
     */
    public function add($data) {
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
            $this->db->update('sch_settings', $data);
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('sch_settings', $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }

    public function getCurrentSession() {
        $session_result = $this->get();
        return $session_result[0]['session_id'];
    }

    public function getCurrentSessionName() {
        $session_result = $this->get();
        return $session_result[0]['session'];
    }

    public function getCurrentSchoolName() {
        $session_result = $this->get();
        return $session_result[0]['name'];
    }

    public function getStartMonth() {
        $session_result = $this->get();
        return $session_result[0]['start_month'];
    }

    public function getCurrentSessiondata() {
        $session_result = $this->get();
        return $session_result[0];
    }

    public function getDateYmd() {
        return date('Y-m-d');    }

    public function getDateDmy() {
        return date('d-m-Y');
    }

}
```

What could be the error and kindly help to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried with `PHP 5+`??

Comment: Please check your "base_url" in config/config.php

Comment: @Star_Man Base is like ```$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/school-erp/';```

Comment: @prabhu, same thing works fine in another computer contains php 7.

Comment: Did you check the permission to `index.php` of `CodeIgniter` and folder?? Because I've faced this kind of problems when I had shifted the project from one server to another.

Comment: Set routes path in routes.php file ..

Comment: @prabhu, May i know the command for checking permissions?

Comment: Replace `error_reporting(-1);` to `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: And If Controller filename is starts with small letter make it upper case.

Comment: @Artier, ```error_reporting(E_ALL);``` does nothing and all controller name is in upper case only.

Comment: In `case 'production': ` change `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: It displays an error, ```Message: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Filename: /home/mani/dev/htdocs/school-erp/application/models/Setting_model.php```

Comment: Can you please add Setting_model code

Comment: I hav eadded the Setting_model code in my question.

Comment: `if($query->num_rows()>0){
if ($id != null) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return $query->result_array();
    }}`Try This

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `case 'production':` change `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in index.php

Comment: It displays, ```Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean```

Comment: check this `if($query !== FALSE && $query->num_rows() >0)`

Comment: A SELECT query will only return a FALSE value when the query fails to even execute.

Comment: Error in another file, ```Message: Call to a member function result() on boolean

Filename: /home/mani/dev/htdocs/school-erp/application/language/english/message_lang.php```

Comment: I think Your queries are not working and return FALSE. Check database setting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161972/discussion-between-artier-and-mani-raj).

Comment: The issue is with database connection and fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check few things:

- `base_url`
- htaccess RewriteBase
- permissions
- add error_reporting(1) in index.php and see what errors are reporting

Comment: Base is like ```$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/school-erp/';```

Comment: OK check permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

Lot of things could be happening:

1) You must have an .htaccess file on your project root label (school-erp in this case). Open the .htaccess file and paste:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) school-erp/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ school-erp/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

2) Check your database.php file. You can find it in school-erp -> application -> config -> database.php

It is extremely important the same database name, password and user in this file and on your DBMS have the database created with these same parameters. Remember codeigniter won't show any page if you have a config string on database.php that currently not match with what you have on your DBMS.

3) Open a terminal as root user then change directory to the current path of your project which this way:

```
cd var/www/
```

Then you must give the necesary permisions to school-erp folder and all contained in it. You can do it using this instruction:

```
chmod 667 school-erp -R
```

Be carefull with the permision code you give to your files... chmod 777 isn't appropiate to production enviroments (I don't even use it on my localhost).

4) Your current base_url will work if you have this folder structure (I will post it as a path):

```
var/www/school-erp
```

Why I say this? because some server instalations come with an extra folder level. This folder is called normally "html". If this happens the path will be changed to:

```
var/www/html/school-erp
```

Which means you will need to change your base_url too.

5) Check in the other system the navigation bar of the browser when you enter to the index of the project (localhost/school-erp) if it doesn't appear "index.php" in the url it means that the server is rewriting the url so you will have to follow step 1) I posted on this answer plus turning on the a2enmod rewrite of apache server.